# "Cannot read property 'hub' of undefined" in aspx page with declare SignalR Library

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have added SignalR script in my ASPX page. But when the page loads:, it gets error in console: Cannot read property 'hub' of undefined. Here my code: ( all of this code is placed in "asp:Content" tag)

```
<script src="/Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="/Js/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script> 

    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="http://myhost/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            console.log($.connection);
            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://myhost/signalr';
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub1;
        });     

    </script>
```

When I declare this script in plain html page, it works successfully.

Anyone have idea. Thanks.

Code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgmaF.jpg)

Error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IESfq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens, because your addressing is mismatch.
change

```
<script src="/Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="/Js/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="~/Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="~/Js/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
```

And be sure that the "jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js" and "jquery-1.10.2.min.js" files are in the "js" folder in root directory of your site.

Comment: Sr. Js folder is in my root folder of my site. And my script src is correct. Adding ~ then it is not still true.

Comment: Then, may be the problem is related to the hubs referencing: <script src="http://myhost/signalr/hubs"></script>

Comment: No, all references are correct ( because in other plain html, it is ok). But when I put all <script> tag in html root tag ( like <html>, <body>...) of my aspx page. It loads library successfully. When it's in <asp:Content> root tag, it gets error like that.